# javascript array.push inside for loop--result not array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to populate an array by using a for loop to access certain records in a database and then combine the contents of some DB fields with text to create each array element.  Here's what I have:

```
var numbers = [7,8];
var phsw = [];
for (var i=0,len=numbers.length;i<len;i++) {
    selectObj = cObj.select().from("wp_posts").where('ID=?', numbers[i]);
    result1 = cObj.exec(selectObj);
    var resource = result1[0].guid;
    var title = result1[0].post_title;
    var tnTxt = result1[0].post_title;
    var tn = resource.replace(/\.jpg/,"-150x150.jpg");
    phsw.push({mytitle:'" + title + "', mythumbnail:'" + tn + "', mytntxt:'" + tnTxt + "', myresource:'" + resource +"'});
    }
```

This creates what I thought was an array, except it's apparently not really an array. When I use console.log(phsw) to see what's in it I get this:

[{mytitle:'title', mythumbnail:'imagefile1tnlink', mytntxt:'thumbtxt1', myresource:'imagefile1link'},{mytitle:'title2', mythumbnail:'imagefile2tnlink', mytntxt:'thumbtxt2', myresource:'imagefile2link'}]

where I should get this:

[object Object]

if it was really an array (right??).

I'm using this in Application Craft, and the phsw array is being created with server side javascript and then being passed to a callback on the application side, but when it gets back to the app side, I can't use it to populate a widget because it's not really an array. How can I make sure phsw is an array?

And yes, I'm sure this code isn't the most clean or efficient way to do this; my (rather rusty) experience is in PHP and MySQL as opposed to javascript, so I'm always open to suggestions of better ways to do things!

Comment: If it was an array the type would be `[object Array]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No everything is correct. It is in fact an array containing exactly 2 objects.

Your expectation that you should get [object Object] is wrong.

Comment: Okay, but when I use console.log(result1), I get [object Object] and result1 is an array. Why wouldn't I get the same result from console.log(phsw) if phsw was an array?

Comment: How do you know that result1 is an array?

Comment: console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(phsw)); or console.log(Array.isArray(phsw)); or do it with result1

Comment: I actually do not think result1 is an array. Maybe it is an object with a property named 0.

Comment: When I use console.log(Array.isArray(phsw)); and console.log(Array.isArray(result1)); they both return true. However, somehow, I'm still not getting the results I need in the callback because the array isn't formed properly somehow. BUT--that's a separate question, and this one has been answered--thank you Jacob, and everyone else for your comments. :-)